# Recreating Nested Static Class in Java using C Sharp

Tags: java, c#, static

I am working on porting a code from Java to C Sharp. In Java I have the following class.

```
public class ClassA{
    ...
    private List<ClassA.ClassB> classBs = new ArrayList();

    public classA(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            this.classBs.add(new ClassA.ClassB());
        }
    }

    public static class ClassB{
        private int value;

        public ClassB(){
            this.value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to notice is that, in line

> this.classBs.add(new ClassA.ClassB());

we are creating an instance of a Static Inner Class.

Now, in C sharp, I am not able to re-create the same static inner class.
After researching, I found I can only do the one of the following,

1. Make the inner class classB non-static or make all the members of classB as static.
2. Define classB outside classA.

Neither seem to recreate the exact code of Java. How do I proceed with this?

Comment: _"Note: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience."_ - [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) - So, I think you're down to first half of 1. or 2. which with lack of further information is rather opinion based.

Comment: The second statement makes me lean towards creating the class outside. Maybe I can try Using a different namespace to combine these classes. Thanks @Fildor

Comment: Isn't all inner classes in C# are static?

Comment: Initialized Static Class?  is this really work in java

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by initialized static class. But yeah, i wrote the above code based on what's working in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java nested static class is very similar to a regular C# nested class:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private IList<ClassB> classBs = new List<ClassB>();

    public ClassA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.classBs.Add(new ClassB());
        }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        internal int value;

        public ClassB()
        {
            this.value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```